# Sudden spike in app Removes - what's changed?

Tags: facebook

I previously asked this question on the Facebook forums but apparently they want us to come here. Even though it's not a programming question, I thought I'd ask it here.

Anyone any ideas?

---

Starting on Aug 17th, our app has suddenly experienced a huge spike in Removes/Uninstalls.

According to our numbers, since then, Removes have spiked and then settled at almost twice our daily average. For 2 months prior, we have not had a massive, extended spike like this and we have heard nothing from our users in terms of feedback on any issue that would cause this.

Was there a change in Facebook last week that would have caused this? Perhaps something making removing the app easier or something suddenly increasing the visibility of the app signficantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you correlate the spike with an increase in usage (apache logs, insights install logs)? Maybe you had a small viral spurt but it wasn't what your users were expecting?

Comment: The increase in Removes wasn't accompanied by a similar growth in installs or viral activity or page views. We see fluctuations in other stats (such an elevated clickthrough rate from Streams) but the pattern in increase and decrease don't correlate.

Comment: Increased visability of viral activity (stream namely) leading to click throughs could be correlating with more users seeing your stream stories and not wanting them (leading to the remove app).

Comment: Matt is right. Any elevation on raw stream views?

Comment: Right, this is one of my guesses too - that something Facebook did increased the visibility of the Stream Posts and many people didn't want them. However, I'm wondering if this means that Facebook's recent virality changes have greatly increased the amount of Stream posts delivered to existing (but inactive)users (since we have not seen an increase in Blocks, I assume that non-users aren't being as affected). Unfortunately, since Facebook Insights isn't working, I haven't been able to check out Stream views but otherwise, Streams hasn't shown any activity as dramatic as the spike in Removes.